# Qtcreator GUI: how to modify highlighted entries' appearance?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

### Question

Is there any way to make the highlighting entries more discernible?

Here is the screenshot illustrating what I mean by highlighted entries:
[image: Qtcreator GUI showing the highlighted entries]

### Problem

I am having a hard time spotting highlighted entries in qtcreator. And I could not find a proper setting that can be modified, e.g., in `Text Editor => Font & Colors`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to go on *Tools -> Options -> Font and Colours* and than change the background colour of *occurrences*

[image]

If it doesn't permit you to do it, click the copy button before.

And this is the result

[image]